# typeScript error '{ type: string; directory: string; webkitdirectory: string; }'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, script, type

Tengo el siguiente error, usarndo los atributos directory="" webkitdirectory="" type="file". en un input en jsx, usando react.js.

codigo

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  useEffect(()=>{

  },[])

const [rootFolder, setRootFolder] = useState('');

const readNamesFolders =()=>{

}



  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>
          Extraer metadata de carpetas
       
      </p>
      <p style={{fontSize:15}}>
Seleccione la carpeta raiz donde se contienen las carpetas con los archivos fotograficos
          </p>
    {rootFolder?  (  <p>
         Carpeta raiz: {rootFolder}
        </p>):null}

        <input type="file" directory="" webkitdirectory="" />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

el objetivo es seleccionar multiples carpetas y sus archivos.
me muestra eel siguiente error

'

```
    TypeScript error in /home/gett/extract-metadata-picture/src/App.tsx(32,28):
Type '{ type: string; directory: string; webkitdirectory: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.
  Property 'directory' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.  TS2322
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hola estas trabajando con TS o con JS ? probé tu código  no me dio el error que mencionas, he visto ese error en TS y sucede cuando no declaras los tipos , reinstala tus dependencias, a mi el código me funciona bien